# Trying to avoid ESLint rule in React with HOC and useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a React functional [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that works correctly, but it violates the ESLint rule `react/display-name`. Here is the code:

```
export const withTheme = (WrappedComponent) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
  return props => {
    const ctx = useContext(ThemeContext)
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} darkTheme={ctx.darkTheme} toggleTheme={ctx.toggleTheme}/>
  }
}
```

If I fix it by naming the function like I think is the intent (as follows):

```
export const withTheme = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return func;
  function func(props) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    const ctx = useContext(ThemeContext)
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} darkTheme={ctx.darkTheme} toggleTheme={ctx.toggleTheme}/>
  }
}
```

I get the ESLint error `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

How can I fix this so I get the HOC to work (as it does) and not have any ESLint errors?

Comment: Random idea, maybe change `func` to uppercase `Func`? Perhaps the linter will see it as a component then

Comment: You might want to [read about what](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md) the [ESLint rules do](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-exactly-do-the-lint-rules-enforce).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Great random idea! That worked. Any thoughts on how to get rid of the named function without violating another eslint rule (I asked it as a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955853/looking-for-a-clean-way-to-use-lamba-in-react-hoc-without-using-a-named-function

Comment: Thanks for the thought @HereticMonkey. I did look at that and it only has examples with class components and not functional. It did not help me sadly.

Comment: Did you try doing `withTheme.displayName = "withTheme";`? That appears suggested by the first link. The second suggests that it's due to your hook not being named with a `use` prefix.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I'm not following where you are suggesting I put `withTheme.displayName = '..'` in my code.

Comment: After the code you have written. `export const withTheme = ...; withTheme.displayName = "withTheme";` Just a guess based on that page though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) that the linter enforces are:

> Don't call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> - Call Hooks from React function components.
> - Call Hooks from custom Hooks

Your `function func` looks, to the linter, like just a normal function - *not* a component, and as a result, it prohibits calling a hook (`useContext`) inside it. If you change `func` to `Func`, the uppercase function name will then be recognized as a React component.

```
export const withTheme = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return Func;
  function Func(props) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    const ctx = useContext(ThemeContext)
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} darkTheme={ctx.darkTheme} toggleTheme={ctx.toggleTheme}/>
  }
  // or: return function Func(props) { ...
}
```

(though if you don't care for a name other than `func`, some would argue that it'd make more sense to ignore `react/display-name` here than to add less than meaningful code)

Comment: Agreed on the name.  I’ve been also trying to avoid naming it unsuccessfully. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955853/looking-for-a-clean-way-to-use-lamba-in-react-hoc-without-using-a-named-function